# Django check constraint for datetime

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    creation_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    expiration_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
  
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check=####
            )
        ]
```

I am trying to write a check constraint to ensure that `expiration_dateime > creation_dateime`. I am unable to find a way to do it correctly with Q objects, help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

For Django 3.1:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F, Q

class MyModel(models.Model):
    creation_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    expiration_datetime = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(expiration_dateime__gt=F('creation_datetime')),
                name="mycustomconstraint_check1"
            )
        ]
```

Using F expresions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions.

And more specific: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters.

Answer (score 0):

`Model.clean()`

> This method should be used to provide custom model validation, and to
> modify attributes on your model if desired. For instance, you could
> use it to automatically provide a value for a field, or to do
> validation that requires access to more than a single field

> Note, however, that like `Model.full_clean()`, a model’s `clean()`
> method is not invoked when you call your model’s `save()` method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: I would like to have validation in the model layer, preferably low level validation in the database itself. The clean method is apparently only called when validating forms, which is unsuited for my requirements: it allows invalid object creation without raising any exception.

Comment: the form’s `clean()` and Models `clean()`  methods are totally unrelated if you're not using `ModelForm`. You could call Models `clean()` inside `Model.save()` method. And if you take a look at the link errors can be raised in Models clean() method too.